# Using not with both, either, neither: word choice when expressing negation of two options

Tags: grammaticality, negation, logic, multiple-negation

In a sentence responding negatively to multiple statements or questions,
which of the following ways sounds best and has the least grammatical error?

1. He didn’t do both.
2. He didn’t do either.
3. He didn’t do neither.
4. He didn’t do none.
5. He did neither.
6. He did none.

If there are any grammatical issues with the sentence, please explain why.

Comment: So he has two things to do? Did he do zero or one of them? "He didn't do both" suggests he might have done one.

Answer (score 1):

OP's *He didn’t do neither* and *He didn’t do none* are like ***I didn't do nuffink**!*

They're all ***double negatives***, usually seen as evidence of poor education if uttered by native speakers. Sometimes it's competent speakers facetiously imitating "the great unwashed" and other "deplorables", but non-native speakers should probably *always* avoid such usages.

Comment: I'd add that **He didn’t do both** might need special context to work. "He painted and carpeted." "No. He didn’t do both. Just the painting."

Comment: True, but by that token, all the ***either*** and ***neither*** sentences need "special context" (i.e. *exactly and only* two alternatives). Come to that, so does *He did none* (since unlike the potentially independent utterance *He did **nothing***, it requires context for *...none of **what**?*).